# Fedex International orders - commodity value

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, fedex

how to add a commodity value to each of the products in Magento. Because this is missing, we are not getting the correct shipping quotes from FEDEX for international orders. we have tried searching around the back end, but can't seem to find anything relating to this issue. Can anyone please let me know if you have a solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Ant help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

shipping quotes at fedex depends on:

- package type (eg: pak)
- recipient zone (eg: zone 4 -> japan)
- weight (0.5 up to 68kgs for international priority).
- ODA: if its an out of delivery area package eg: okinawa in japan.

the value will only impact the rate if you select "declared value" instead of "customs value".

- declared value: you request fedex to make an insurance of the declared value: eg: 500usd. fedex charge like 0.50usd for each 100usd you request for insurance.
- customs value: the amount of money the product costs in order to classify your products and pay taxes abroad.

I believe that you must check if the transaction is including customs value or declared value. probably you will have a precise quotation with that information.